# Can't upload 2 images in a single NSURL request in POST method

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ipad, nsurlrequest

We are sending right post request to API by multi parting both the image data.So,there  is an issue  both image are not uploading, just  a single image is uploading to server. I have checked the parameter name which are as same provided from API team, here is it:-

```
#define IMAGE_DP @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileimage\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"

#define IMAGE_COVER @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coverimage\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
```

**Building request to upload two images in a single NSURLMutable request**

```
 if ([isprofilepicupdated isEqualToString:@"1"]) {


        [postBody appendData:[IMAGE_DP dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:profileimage]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    if ([iscoverpicupdated isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [postBody appendData:[IMAGE_COVER dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:coverimage]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```

**So how can we append two images in single body of NSURLMutable request?**

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *urlString = @"<PostImage-url>";
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


        // file
        for (int i=0;i<(YOUR _ARRAY).count;i++)
        {
            UIImage * myimg=[YOUR _ARRAY objectAtIndex:i];
            NSData *ImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimg);

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"img1[]\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:ImageData]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        }

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"vin\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // close form
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // set request body
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        //ASynchronous request

        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```